# How do I crop a string?

Tags: string, text, vbscript

Ho do I crop a string in VB Script?

Example:

```
myString = "object(value)"
newString = crop myString then remove the string inside '()'
echo newString
```

then the output would be the string: `object()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `Mid` and `InStr`

```
myString = "object(value)"
newString = Mid(myString, 1, InStr(myString, "(")) & ")"
```

This assumes that there is only one occurrence of `(` in the string.